# Store device information when application uninstalled Android

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play

Is there a way to store or know the device information when the application is uninstalled?

Can this be achieved with Google Analytics or Google Play?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Google Analytics is used to get all the events and statistics inside the Application. It is impossible to use Google Analytics to track every Application uninstalls. Google Play Store on the other hand stores the count of the  uninstall your app had. Go to your app in play store >> Statistics >> drop down >> Daily uninstalls by device >> in second graph select device >> here you find daily uninstall based on the devices.

Comment: Yes, all the data I want is there. Please post a response to this question and I will mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Analytics is used to get all the events and statistics inside the Application. It is impossible to use Google Analytics to track every Application uninstalls. Google Play Store on the other hand stores the count of the uninstall your app had. Go to your app in play store >> Statistics >> drop down >> Daily uninstalls by device >> in second graph select device >> here you find daily uninstall based on the devices.

Already answered in comments.